# Printf for struct? (C/C++, VC2008)

Tags: c++, struct, printf, field

Just build&run this in VC2008:

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};
A a = { 10, 20, 30 };
printf("%d %d %d\n", a);
```

Is it normal?

```
10 20 30
```

I'd like to cast! but it don't works:

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   operator int()
   {
      return a + b + c;
   }
};
A a = { 10, 20, 30 };
printf("%d\n", a);
```

output is only:

```
10
```

I need auto-casting for template-utility.
Here it is: https://code.google.com/p/boolib/source/browse/boolib/crypt/ShakedValue.h
It should hide in memory value, that any hack-programms (ArtMoney) can't find value.

And one more trick usage: **Print private members of the struct/class**

Comment: It means printf() will not use any casts for stucts/classes. Operators like "operator int();" can't help.

Comment: I can confirm it happens with gcc too.

Comment: So your edits make it clear that you really are talking about C++. This has nothing to do with C. Use C++ IO, overload the `<<` operator and stuff like that. Don't expect a C function and concept to solve C++ problems.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a cast, then cast it:

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   operator int()
   {
      return a + b + c;
   }
};
A a = { 10, 20, 30 };
printf("%d\n", (int)a);
```

the output will be

```
60
```

Comment: Yes. But i want auto-cast. My class A is a template tool, and it has casting to template parameter: operator T(); It should be auto-casting to T in printf.

Comment: It will autocast when an argument of type `int` is expected. However, varargs have no type until the call to `va_arg`, so they're not autocast.

Comment: @k06a, you won't ever get that, so start looking into alternatives, like having a template member function `template T toT<T>() { return (T)this; }` or something similar.

Comment: And user of my template should write value.toT() instead of value. Not nice :(

Comment: Here is my template - https://code.google.com/p/boolib/source/browse/boolib/crypt/ShakedValue.h It hides variables in memory, that any hack-programms cant find value.

Comment: @k06a, what about overriding `int operator()` to return the sum and using it like `printf("%d\n", a());`

Comment: @k06a, or just stick with `cout` and write type-safe methods to handle your type, that's what they're there for! Plus `cout` is faster than `printf` if that matters :)

Comment: Blindy thanks for more attractive form with "operator")) About cout - i can't make users of my class not to use printf().

Answer (score 5):

It's undefined behavior, so in a certain sense every possible behavior can be termed "normal" for this function call. It can be explained though.

`printf` takes a variable number of arguments after the format string. How these are packed is left to the implementation. It seems that Visual C++ packs the arguments in memory the same way it packs the members of your `struct A`, so every time it calls `va_arg` internally, it gets the next element in `a`.

As regards the casting, you can't rely on autocasting in a varargs context, since the optional parameters have no type. `printf` is declared as `int printf(char const *, ...)`. `...` is a range of untyped parameters.

Comment: And here's the link to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) that explicitly states: "The results are undefined if there are not enough arguments for all the format specifications".

Comment: It's undefined anyway since the type of `a` doesn't much what is expected for `%d`.

Comment: Is it possible to make it auto-casting to int?

Comment: May be you know type-safe form of printf() ?

Comment: I/O streams are an option; so is Boost::Format, a more direct replacement for `printf` and relatives. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/index.html

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing like C/C++, your code is just a mixture of the two. In particular it doesn't compile with a standard C compiler because you are missing the `struct` keyword in the declaration of `a`.

For your use of `printf`. First of all you shouldn't if this is C++. It has its own mechanisms for IO. Use them.

Then placing a structure as an argument in a `...` list is undefined behavior. You just had bad luck, and the compiler did what it did. It could just have sad "no, no, don't do that", or at least have given you a warning.

Answer (score 4):

You placed three integers on the stack, and then retrieved three integers (one per "%d"). Yes, it is normal - but in the realm of "really *ugly* hack" (and Undefined Behaviour to boot, as plinth correctly commented).

Comment: And if your struct packing is different than your stack packing, you're SOL. (in other words this is NOT portable).

Comment: I'm actually very surprised that that's how structs are passed as arguments, I'd have thought it was more like passing a pointer or something.

Comment: @Blindy *Everything* in C is passed by value. If you want something to be passed by reference, you have to do it yourself (i.e., take the address and pass the pointer - which is in turn passed by value).

Comment: That's not entirely true, at least for return values, they get passed through the `eax` register even when they're bigger objects by passing just the pointer transparently, unless RVO is in effect.

Comment: @Blindy: What the CPU does has nothing to do with it. On the C language level, everything is passed by value. If you want pass-by-reference semantics, you have to pass a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

This works by accident.  Most times when your `printf` arg count or types do not match the results will not be pretty.

If you want C++ use `ostream/cout`

```
std::cout << a.a << ' ' << a.b << ' ' << a.c << std::endl;
```

If you want non-brittle C code use:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", a.a, a.b, a.c);
```

Comment: @k06a - I see - that was not clear when I put this in as a response :-(

Comment: Thank you for response anywhere)

Answer (score 2):

it's because of memory layout of the struct. the ints are straight after each other. so putting the struct in the printf call is basically putiing the same as putting each one on one after the other

Comment: Why there is no warning, like in GCC? - Line 12: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'main()::A'
Line 12: warning: too few arguments for format

Comment: Apparently, VC2008 doesn't do format string checking. A compiler is not obliged to do that and may accept code such as yours. The C standard simply doesn't specify what behavior the compiled code should display.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a warning in vs2008 too, you might have disabled it, or it's not enabled by default. I only have 2010 to test with right now though.

Comment: No any warning for default properties (vs2008)

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of compiler/environment dependent stuff in how printf might behave.

printf ostensibly uses C's var args features where when you have a declaration

```
 int printf(char* formatStr, ...)
```

you can pass multiple arguments in the "...". Then in the body of printf you would do something like the following

```
// count how many formatters are in the format string 
// and calculate "amount"
// here amount = 3
va_list valsToPrint;
va_start(valsToPrint,amount);    
for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
{
    // treat each value as a 32-bit int and print it
}

va_end(vl);
```

The important thing is -- there's a lot of compiler/environment dependent stuff in here. Such as the fact that the struct is probably packed so that each value shows up on 32-bit boundaries and how the va_list is actually determined from the compiler. I imagine compiler-to-compiler there could be some very different behavior from your code, but its not entirely surprising that exhibits the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 1):

printf() has "(char *, ...)" signature. That means it is up to "printf" function to handle all arguments after "char *".

You pass a struct A to printf(). In memory it has following layout: "int, int, int". printf() function reads format string ("%d %d %d") and "thinks" that you passed 3 integers to it. And this "assumption" coincides with the struct's layout. So it prints all its fields as separate values.

Try to remove "b" field and you will see that printf() will print values of "a" field, "c" field and ***SEGMENTATION FAULT***.

Comment: Explaining it would be more helpful than hoping for rep. :)